# how to setup socks5 proxy server on centos9 for network access behind firewall?

Tags: centos, security, proxy, linux-networking, socks

I need a socks proxy on centos 9, to access services from an (internal) network behind a firewall.

It should be a socks 5 proxy (dynamic port forwarding) that can only be used by the configured ssh users on the system.

Only destinations from the internal network should be reachable. For example, no external destinations/websites on the Internet should be addressed via the socks proxy.

```
client 
   ===SSH tunnel (from external network)
      ===> SSH-server 
           ---internal network (only)
              ---> https Server ...
```

The client can initiate tunnel with dynamic port forwarding and use the ssh connection as a socks5 proxy.

```
ssh -D 1080 -q -C -N SSH-server
```

There is no need to configure something socks proxy related on the SSH-server?

I noticed dante-server, but there is no repo and it seems to be no official solution. What is the advantage?

I could not find something to limit the forwarded connections.

How can I set up such a socks proxy?

Comment: What did you try so far? Or you expect we will do your work?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.